# How can I get download table from Databricks on my local machine if I don't have select privileges

Tags: blob, databricks

I have a client Databricks workspace where there are some Databricks SQL tables, I need to get these tables to my blob storage. But because of restricted privileges in the databricks workspace I can't write the tables from my spark data-frames to blob, and I also don't have access to DBFS on databricks.
I can display and download the small tables, but there are some tables that have 200 million records, how can I download these tables to my local machine?